# JSF F:AJAX вопрос по передаче в качестве параметров значения бина

Tags: java, html, ajax, веб-программирование, jsf

Доброе утро!
Помогите решить задачку , пожст.
Код ajax события :

```
 <h:form>
        <h:panelGroup class="form-group col-lg-8">
            <label for="usr">Поиск:</label>
                <h:inputText class="form-control" id="searchParam"  value="#{searchBeen.serchInput}" >
                </h:inputText>
        </h:panelGroup>
        <h:panelGroup class="form-group col-lg-3">
            <label for="sel1">Поиск по:</label>
            <select class="form-control" id="sel1">
              <option>Название</option>
              <option>Автор</option>
            </select>
            </h:panelGroup>
               <h:commandButton class="btn btn-default col-lg-1" style="margin-top: 23px;" value="Найти">
                   <f:ajax event="click" render=":booksContent"  listener="#{booksList.formArrayListBySearch(searchBeen.serchInput)}"/>
               </h:commandButton>
           </h:form>
```

Код слушателя для listener="#{booksList.formArrayListBySearch(searchBeen.serchInput)}" :

```
public void formArrayListBySearch(String sp){
    System.out.println("Отрабатывает функция поиска нужных книг : " + sp); 
}
```

В консоль получаем :

> Отрабатывает функция поиска нужных книг :

Ходя поле инпут бокса заполнено

Comment: Вроде нельзя так передавать параметр `booksList.formArrayListBySearch(searchBeen.serchInput)`. Можно сделать разве что так `#{trader.buy('SOMESTOCK')}`. Почитайте: https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/jsf-el003.htm#BNAHU

Comment: Да , судя по всему - нельзя , спасибо
А внутри функции можно добраться до значения этого бина ?

Comment: Да, программно можно. Если будет доступ.

Comment: Не сказал важную вещь. Сам бин, в таком случае, нужно будет получить через `FacesContext`, Через `new SearchBeen()` ничего не выйдет, так как вы просто создадите новый обьект у которого поле `serchInput` будет иметь значение по умолчанию. И еще у Вас есть несколько синтаксических ошибок: 1. `SearchBeen` - правильно `Bean` (бин), 2. `serchInput` - вероятно хотели `searchInput`. Хотя возможно Вы так и задумывали =)

Comment: не могу разобраться , как добраться до этого бина

Comment: можете подсказать ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2633112/get-jsf-managed-bean-by-name-in-any-servlet-related-class

Answer (score 0):

Вызов методов с параметрами был добавлен в Expression Language 2.2. Возможно используется контейнер без поддержки EL2.2 либо загружается более ранняя версия.